# Implementing Footer Hiding on 404 Pages in Next.js 14

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

I would like to create a 404 page (not-found.tsx) within the root path of my app router. Currently, it functions well, displaying a shared header and footer across all pages and posts.

However, when a not-found page is accessed, the footer is still visible. I wish to hide it from the layout in such cases. Is there a specific check within Next.js 14 to determine if it's a 404 page and hide the footer?

Personally, thought having a custom component 404 and redirect to it. But then, I am still facing the problem that the layout loads first.

Here is my code:

```
import "styles/main.css"

import { Suspense } from "react"

import { Metadata } from "next"
import dynamic from "next/dynamic"
import { draftMode } from "next/headers"

import { toPlainText } from "@portabletext/react"

import favicon from "@/images/logo.jpg"

import { Footer } from "@/components/global/Footer"
import { Navbar } from "@/components/global/Navbar"
import { GoogleAnalytics } from "@/components/shared"

import { loadHomePage, loadSettings } from "@/sanity/loader/loadQuery"

const VisualEditing = dynamic(() => import("@/sanity/loader/VisualEditing"))

export async function generateMetadata(): Promise<Metadata> {
  const [{ data: settings }, { data: homePage }] = await Promise.all([
    loadSettings(),
    loadHomePage()
  ])

  const metadataBase =
    (settings.website_url && new URL(settings.website_url)) || new URL("http://localhost:3000")

  const site_name = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_TITLE ?? ""

  const disableIndex = settings.noIndex
    ? { index: false, follow: false }
    : { index: true, follow: true }

  return {
    metadataBase,
    creator: site_name,
    authors: [{ name: "Tajko" }],
    robots: disableIndex,
    icons: {
      icon: [
        {
          url: favicon.src,
          sizes: "any",
          type: "image/jpg"
        }
      ]
    },
    title: homePage?.title
      ? {
          template: `%s • ${homePage.title}`,
          default: homePage.title || "Personal website"
        }
      : undefined,
    description: homePage?.overview ? toPlainText(homePage.overview) : undefined
  }
}

export default async function IndexRoute({ children }: Children) {
  const { data: settings } = await loadSettings()

  const gtmID = settings?.gtmID

  return (
    <>
      <Suspense>
        <Navbar />
      </Suspense>
      <Suspense>{children}</Suspense>
      <Suspense>
        <Footer />
      </Suspense>
      {draftMode().isEnabled && <VisualEditing />}
      <GoogleAnalytics GA_TRACKING_ID={gtmID!} />
    </>
  )
}
```

not-found.tsx:

```
const NotFound = () => {
  return (
    <section className="select-none col-span-full overflow-hidden text-white bg-black absolute top-0 left-0 z-0 w-full h-full px-5 md:px-10 flex flex-col items-center justify-center place-content-center">
      <div className="z-[100] flex w-full flex-wrap gap-[15px] max-w-[90%] lg:max-w-[920px] place-content-center items-center">
        <h1 className="hero z-[10] font-micro-medium text-[38px] leading-tight text-white md:text-headingL inline-block">
          Page not found
        </h1>
      </div>

      <video
        src="https://i.makeagif.com/media/2-07-2016/Otm80Z.mp4"
        autoPlay
        loop
        muted
        playsInline
        className="absolute w-screen h-screen top-0 left-0 object-cover"
      />

      <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 w-screen h-screen bg-black/40 z-10"></div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default NotFound
```

Comment: unfortunately there is no hacky way to handle this